# django / Can filter via foreignKey?

Tags: django

Is there any way filter via foreignObject

see my code, which I want to fix.

model Part :

```
class UserProfile:
    blahblah

class FreeTime : 
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    fromTime=models.DateField()
    toTime=models.DateField()
```

Now, coding part

```
givenTime = date(2012,11,11)


freeTimes = FreeTime.objects.filter(fromTime__lte=givenTime, toTime__gte=givenTime)

users = []
for freeTime in freeTimes:
    users.append(freeTime.owner)

//todo : remove duplicated object of user
```

This is totally waste of code.

As you see, what I want to is, find user who is free at given time.

Any way to reduce the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
User.objects.filter(freetime__fromTime__lte=givenTime, freetime__toTime__gte=givenTime)
```

**EDIT:**

As @calvin Cheng says, you should FK to User:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class FreeTime(models.Model): 
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    fromTime=models.DateField()
    toTime=models.DateField()
```

Comment: Yup. Beat me to it. But may I point out that for his question, he is Fk-ing back to `UserProfile` class. Not `User`.  Although you are probably right that it is a better design to FK back to `User` class and I would do it your way.

Comment: True. I always FK to auth.models.User. I think it's a best practice. With Django 1.5 we won't have this problem anymore.

Comment: Is there any difference? accessing userProfile via user.get_profile() or accessing user via UserProfile.user. Usually valuable data is in userProfile, not user. so i use userprofile as foreignKey. what is the difference?